# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on Server side in CORBA C++/Java application

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, corba, omniorb

I have such code:

```
interface Employee
{
    string getLastname();
};

#include "Employee.idl"

interface Work
{
    Employee getEmployee(in short id);
};
```

**Server files:**

```
#include "Employee.hh"

class EmployeeImpl : public POA_Employee
{
    private:
        char* lastname;
        int id;

    public:
        EmployeeImpl(const char* lastname, int id);
        char* getLastname();
};

#include "EmployeeImpl.h"

EmployeeImpl::EmployeeImpl(const char* lastname, int id)
{
    this->lastname = const_cast<char*>(lastname);
    this->id = id;
}

char* EmployeeImpl::getLastname()
{
    return this->lastname;
}

#include "Work.hh"
#include <vector>
#include "EmployeeImpl.h"
using namespace std;

class WorkImpl : public POA_Work
{
    private:
        vector<EmployeeImpl> employees;

    public:
        WorkImpl();
        Employee_ptr getEmployee(::CORBA::Short id);
};

#include "WorkImpl.h"

 WorkImpl::WorkImpl()
 {
    EmployeeImpl ei1("Doe", 1);
    EmployeeImpl ei2("Smith", 2);
    EmployeeImpl ei3("Brown", 3);

    employees.push_back(ei1);
    employees.push_back(ei2);
    employees.push_back(ei3);
 }

Employee_ptr WorkImpl::getEmployee(::CORBA::Short id)
{
    return employees[id]._this();
}
```

**Client files:**

```
import java.util.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.*;
import org.omg.CORBA.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
     try
     {
        org.omg.CORBA.ORB clientORB = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, null);

        if (clientORB == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem while creating ORB");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = clientORB.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

        Work work = WorkHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str("WorkService"));
        Employee e = work.getEmployee((short)1);
        System.out.println(e.getLastname());
            e = work.getEmployee((short)2);
            System.out.println(e.getLastname());
            e = work.getEmployee((short)3);
            System.out.println(e.getLastname());

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }
    }
}
```

when I run Server, and then client, on client side I see:

> Smith

instead of:

> ```
> Doe
> Smith
> Brown
> ```

and when the client got the message, on server side I see:

> segmentation fault (cope dumped)

and server crashes. Whats wrong with my code guys? I use omniORB and idlj on Kubuntu, and g++ and javac to compile my files.

**Heres my whole project:** http://www44.zippyshare.com/v/60244821/file.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't following the IDL to C++ mapping rules about parameter passing. In particular, on the server:

```
char* EmployeeImpl::getLastname()
{
    return this->lastname;   // this is the problem
}
```

You need to return dynamically allocated memory because the skeleton code is going to deallocate it (with `CORBA::string_free`) after it marshals it over the wire to the client.

This should be:

```
char* EmployeeImpl::getLastname()
{
    return CORBA::string_dup(this->lastname);
}
```

This is all explained in the Henning & Vinowski book *Advanced CORBA Programming with C++*.

The other problem you are having is you are indexing into your vector with a 1-based index. But vector uses a 0-based index scheme. To fix this, either change your client calls, or change your server implementation to something like this:

```
Employee_ptr WorkImpl::getEmployee(::CORBA::Short id)
{
    if (id >= 1 && id <= employees.size())
    { 
       return employees[id - 1]._this();  // convert to 0-based indexing
    }
    else
    {
       // throw some type of exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer after seeing your indexing problem.

Comment: @Brian Neal: thank you so much. I'm still kind a newbie in stackoverflow and Corba too :) And sometimes I dont see obvious things :P Thanks, it helped, of course ;)